# How to remove this link to a non-existent VF page?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

There are many posts about how to emplace links to VF pages into the UI. But I have the opposite problem!

In one page layout for Opportunity, a hyperlink worded "[Edit]" displays. It is to the right of the value, in a formula field, in the Detail tab of a Tabs component on a Lightning Record Page. The purpose of the link must have been: to give the user a way to change the data that is input to the formula field.

But when anyone clicks the link, a blank page displays this text: "Page UpdateOpportunityPricingTier does not exist". In fact the org has no VF page by that name.

So I opened the Page Layout Editor, and there was the field, but nothing next to it about "[Edit]".

In the UI the HTML is unremarkable: span Standard Price Book [ a target="_top" href="/apex/UpdateOpportunityPricingTier?Id=0062J00000qgKAA" Edit /a ] /span  . The ID is that of the Opportunity record.

How does this design generate that? How to fix my UI?

Answer (score 0):

Did you guess it?

I finished typing this, after staring at Setup for  way too long, then I got it.

The link is generated by the formula for the field, which ends with a HYPERLINK(...) function call. The VF Page itself probably disappeared when its managed package was uninstalled.